# Android animated ShapeDrawable

Tags: android

I'm trying to write animated `Drawable` based on `ShapeDrawable` class using some specific `Shape` based class to draw its content.

On demand some values in `Shape` based class should be changed and it should be changed due to these values (something like temperature change on some scale). Whole thing is written for Android 2.1. I found, that call of `invalidateSelf()` for my `ShapeDrawable` should be fine, but I have to provide `Drawable.Callback` for it.

And question is, what should be provided in `invalidateDrawable( Drawable who )` method for `Drawable.Callback` interface? Some samples using such approach:

```
class MyShapeDrawable extends ShapeDrawable implements Drawable.Callback
{
    public void invalidateDrawable( Drawable who ) {
    }

    public void scheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what, long when) {
    }

    public void unscheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what) {
    }
}
```

When I call `invalidateSelf()` for my `ShapeDrawable` based class `invalidateDrawable()` method is called, but what should be done in this method? How to force my `Shape` to be updated and redrawn?

Answer (score 0):

this is the implementation in the android source for View.java...

```
public void invalidateDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    if (verifyDrawable(drawable)) {
        final Rect dirty = drawable.getBounds();
        final int scrollX = mScrollX;
        final int scrollY = mScrollY;

        invalidate(dirty.left + scrollX, dirty.top + scrollY,
                dirty.right + scrollX, dirty.bottom + scrollY);
    }
}
```

Comment: please explain your answer in more detail.